# JavaScript/node.js convert array into regex.match arguments for if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have written a node module with several places that use regular expressions to limit which files are manipulated as below:

```
if (!file.match(/\/node_modules\//) && !file.match(/\/fontawesome\//) && !file.match(/\/docs\//) && !file.match(/\/target\//) && !seenFile[file]) {
    //do some processing
}
```

I'm trying to modify the module to accept user input as an array - i.e.:

```
['/node_modules/', '/fontawesome/', '/docs/', '/target/']
```

Is there a good way to convert the array into the regex?  I know apply might work if I wasn't using file.match but I'm not sure if it will work in this instance.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just trying to figure out what you need: is [this code of any help](https://jsfiddle.net/5qctojap/1/)?

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help.  I was confused about || in js vs. | in regex.

Comment: So, can I post it as an answer? I think there is one mistake: `RegExp(rx)` must be used.

Comment: Please do.  I'll will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array of values to build a dynamic regex:

- Escape all special regex characters with `.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");`
- Build the regex with the help of `|` alternation operator
- Use the regex with `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` methods.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var ar = ['/node_modules/', '/fontawesome/', '/docs/', '/target/'];
ar = ar.map(function(item) {  
          return item.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
       });
var rx = RegExp(ar.join("|"));

var file = "/node_modules/d.jpg";
if (!file.match(rx)) {
    console.log("No stop words found!");
} else {
    console.log("Stop words found!");
}
```